# Installing Xdebug on a remote server (bluehost.com)

Tags: php, xdebug, bluehost

I have xdebug installed and working on my mac but I can't seem to get it installed on my server ( a bluehost.com server). I have been trying for ages and would appreciate any help possible.

Basically I have downloaded 'xdebug.so' and installed it in my /public_html/ directory

I then go into my php.ini file (which is in the same directory) and I remove any other [zend] references and inserted the following:

```
zend_extension=/home1/[myUserName]/public_html/xdebug.so
zend_extension_ts = /home1/[myUserName]/public_html/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
```

This is basically exactly as what I have on my mac and it's working fine.

The reasons I have 'home1' instead of 'home' is because that's how bluehost set up my site. Also I have tried using both just to check but without luck.

When I run phpInfo() I don't get any references to Xdebug.

I'm at a loss here it took me hours to set it up on my mac (months ago) and now I have spent hours trying to set it up on my server.

Note: I have connyacted bluehost.com for help but am still waiting. They also say they don't provide support for such issues so I am not holding my breath.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're on a shared host, you need to have the host install it.

Comment: Suggestion: Never run debug software on a production server.  Run it on a local development machine (your laptop for example), but never run it in production.  It blurs the distinction between development and production and will encourage you to do things you should **never** do (such as debug in production)...

Answer (score 0):

`xdebug.remote_host` points to where X-Debug is supposed to *connect to* when hitting a breakpoint. Unless you're running a debugger on your server, `localhost` needs to be set to your current IP address.

Also, if you're in full control of that server,  install X-Debug "properly". I.e. on a server running Debian, you'd have to `apt-get install php5-xdebug`.

Comment: Thanks for the response!I tried changing the     xdebug.remote_host to my current ip addess (the one on my laptop, not the one the server has) and then tried phpInfo() again without luck. Still no Xdebug unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There is some reasons that might cause this issue:

1. compiled extensions is not compatible with current environment(might cause by compiler, php version, and unexpected config)
2. invalid php.ini configuration (invalid extension_dir, even wrong ini file refer)
3. and more...

---

#### Workable Solution

please refer to official tutorial [here](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/534)

1. Create some necessary directories

`mkdir ~/pecl ~/php ~/php/extensions`

2. Download and extract xdebug into pecl folder

   - for me, I need xdebug v2.5.5 since latest xdebug not support php 5.6

`pecl download xdebug-2.5.5 && tar -xvzf xdebug-2.5.5`

3. Enter xdebug folder and compile the extension

`cd xdebug-2.5.5`

`phpize`

`./config --prefix=$HOME/pecl/xdebug-2.5.5`

`make`

4. Enter modules folder and copy the module to proper location

`cp xdebug.so ~/php/extensions`

5. set extension in php.ini

   - for me, php.ini was created under public_html

> zend_extension=/home{#}/{username}/php/extensions/xdebug.so

6. Create a file called "phpinfo.php" and check whether the xdebug is setup successfully or not.