# Remote debugging with PhPStorm, Bluehost server

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, xdebug, bluehost

Getting Xdebug up and running has been a nightmare.  I uploaded Xdebug to the Bluehost server that houses php.ini.  At the bottom of php.ini, I added:

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="/home2/[My username]/public_html/anthropic/php_xdebug-2.3.2-5.4-vc9.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=[My computer's IP address]
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

I also commented out the following:

```
;zend_loader.disable_licensing=0
;zend_extension=/usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so
```

When I echo phpinfo(); I do not see Xdebug having been installed.  Any help on this is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you have Windows as operating system on your server?

Comment: It's actually Linux...

Comment: Then why are you trying to upload and use Windows-specific `.dll` file?

Comment: Another question: do you have full control over your server .. or is it a shared hosting? For shared hosting you cannot (should not) be able to install and use your custom php extensions. **Related SO questions:** 1) http://stackoverflow.com/q/16685237/783119 ; 2) http://stackoverflow.com/q/4923571/783119